# Why do I get python and perl with the NDK sources?

Tags: android, python, git, perl, android-ndk

I downloaded the sources for Android NDK from the git repository, I noticed that the sources for `perl` and `python` are bundled with the other dependencies: what are this 2 interpreters for ?

Does this means that I can build `python` for Android with the NDK ? Or that if I have a python application I can port it to Android with the NDK ?

Comment: You might want to add links to the git repo and stuff so people can look at what you're talking about. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python and perl are used internally by NDK tools to make the cross-compile environment more friendly. You only need them on the host. NDK can be built for Windows, Mac, or Linux. So the git repository contains all opensource that is required to compile NDK for any of these platforms.